# SQL SELECT everthing with value 5 but not specify from which column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to select something with SQL, and I've a problem with it.

**What I want:**

```
SQL SELECT * FROM table WHERE ? = '5';
```

Select everything which = 5, BUT not specify from which column.

**Example:**

From this ""database"", you should receive the 1st and the last row.

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a condition to your query with `or` keyword so if any of them match the row will be shown as a result
`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE price =5  or height= 5`

better you list your columns by name instead of using * after `SELECT`

Comment: What is the benefit of listing the columns?

Comment: when you use * in your select statement, you are retrieving all the columns on the table, unless if you really need them, otherwise list the columns you need in your select statement. And listing only the columns you need prevent transferring unnecessary bytes across the network , thus improving the performance of you application. Hope this helps.

Comment: Addition to kelech Igbe: Listing only the columns you need makes your source code more readable, because the reader sees, which data you will process.

Comment: okay, thanks guys! In this case it isn't that important I think, because I use every column. But I will for sure remember that and do it in future projects. Also, I am going to change it here for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

You have to list the columns but you can use `in`.  The `where` clause looks like:

```
where 5 in (price, height)
```

Note:  This assumes that the columns have the same type.  You could get type conversion errors if they are not.

Also, given the names of the column and the data, I assume that the columns are stored as numbers.  Hence, I dropped the single quotes around `5`.  If they are really strings, then use the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, how do I combine this with "LIKE"?

Comment: @janisintersim . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: ok. I already got it. I tried the solution of @kelech Igbe and it worked easily with LIKE.